# Java circular frame Ball Animation

Tags: java, animation

I'm new to java. I am like to create a simple animation with a ball moving from left to right and i wish to give it an circular frame illusion(i don't know how to phrase it) If part of the ball leave the border of the frame(right side), that part would reappear in the left side of my frame. I had no idea how to start. So far i only manage to get the ball move.

This is a part of my code

```
public class BallAnimation extends JFrame {


private JButton left,right,up,down;
private Balls ball = new Balls();
private Ellipse2D circle;

public BallAnimation()
{
    add(ball);
}

public class Balls extends JPanel{

private double X=0,Y=0;
private int i=1;
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), (getHeight()));

    if(X==0 && Y ==0)
    {
    X=getWidth()/2.1;
    Y=getHeight()/2.3;
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    circle= new Ellipse2D.Double(X,Y,50,50);
    g2.fill(circle);
    }
    else
    {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        circle= new Ellipse2D.Double(X,Y,50,50);
        g2.fill(circle);
    }
    if(i==1)
    {
        X=X+10;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        repaint();
    }

}
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    BallAnimation test = new BallAnimation();
    test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    test.setSize(700,500);
    test.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

I'd search around and didn't find anything, maybe the phrase im use is not right. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have a Thread.sleep in your paint component method? You'll need more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a simple calculation to check if the ball has gone past the edge of the component.Eg.

```
Rectangle rect = circle.getBounds();
Rectangel bounds = getBounds();

if(rect.getX() + rect.getWidth()>bounds.getWidth()){
    //draw an ellipse that is offset by the width of the component.
    Ellipse2D c2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(circle.getX()-bounds.getWidth(), circle.getY(), circle.getWidth(), circle.getHeight());    
    g2.fill(c2);
}
```

There you go, if it is out of bounds on the right side it will be drawn on the left side.

Here is an example, instead of checking if the ball wraps. I just drew the ball 9 times so that when it is across the boundary it gets drawn.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

/**
 * Created by matt on 11/30/15.
 */
public class BouncingBall {
    int width = 600;
    int height = 600;
    double diameter = 100;
    double v = 10;
    double vx = 6;
    double vy = 8;
    Ellipse2D ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(width/4, height/4, diameter, diameter);
    Ellipse2D post = new Ellipse2D.Double(width/2 - diameter, height/2 - diameter, 2*diameter, 2*diameter);

    JPanel display;
    void buildGui(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ball");

        display = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

                g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2d.fill(post);
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                AffineTransform original = g2d.getTransform();
                for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j<3; j++){
                        AffineTransform wrapper = new AffineTransform(original);
                        wrapper.translate((i-1)*width, (j-1)*height);
                        g2d.setTransform(wrapper);
                        g2d.draw(ball);
                    }
                }
                g2d.setTransform(original);
            }
        };

        display.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        display.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        display.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        frame.setContentPane(display);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

    void startSimulation(){
        while (!Thread.interrupted()&&display.isVisible()) {

            double x = ball.getX() + vx;
            double y = ball.getY() + vy;

            //wrap the ball around.
            if(x>width) x = x-width;
            if(x<0) x = x+width;
            if(y>height) y = y-height;
            if(y<0) y = y+height;

            ball.setFrame(x, y, diameter, diameter);

            //check for collision.

            double dx = ball.getCenterX() - 0.5*width;
            double dy = ball.getCenterY() - 0.5*height;

            double distance = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
            if(distance < 1.5*diameter){
                vx = v*dx/distance;
                vy = v*dy/distance;
            }

            display.repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(33);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BouncingBall b = new BouncingBall();
        EventQueue.invokeAndWait(b::buildGui);
        b.startSimulation();
    }

}
```

Comment: I have some problem here, the ball would be drawn on the left side for one itme. After that , it would not drawn after even if it is out of bounds. Any idea?

Comment: You have a bunch of strange conditionals in your paintComponent, I don't know when/why/where/how they are being set. You'll need to post more of the code.

Comment: @ChiHong I edited the answer with a working example.

Comment: Thank you very much matt.  I will try to understand the coding.